# JavaScript small image on data url

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, data-uri

I am trying to capture the users webcam and upload it to my backend. I found out how to generate a data url (e.g. data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...) from the webcam stream. But the data url is always generated in a 300x150 size. This is way to small to us this image. Do you know how to do it better? I am a javascript newbe.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
  var photo_button = document.querySelector("#photo_button");
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then(function (stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      });
  }

  photo_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        // data url of the image
        console.log(image_data_url);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The size of your video input is accessible as `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the size of your canvas to the video size.

```
  photo_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        canvas.width = video.width;
        canvas.height = video.height;

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        // data url of the image
        console.log(image_data_url);
  });
```

Comment: I changed it to yours but now I get a "data:," in the browser console. nothing more, just that 6 chraracters

Comment: @Kurt does your video element have size attributes? (`width` & `height`)

Comment: @Nora the width and height attribute doesn't necessarily represent the size of the media, only of the Element. The media gets painted by drawImage, so what you need is the size of that media. It's available as `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight`.

Comment: I tried it... doesnt work.